# Material Button Toggle is not sync with model

Tags: angular, angular-material, togglebutton

I have a case when I need to toggle the other button than I'm clicking on. See demo:
[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m32p74-zyrz5n?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbutton-toggle-overview-example.ts)

As you can see I try to do it by:

```
    onToggleGroupChange(event: MatButtonToggleChange) {
    const { value } = event;

    const products =
      event && value.length ? value.map(item => item.value) : undefined;

    if (products) {
      if (products.includes("TWO")) {
        this.selectedItems = ["ONE"];
      }
    }
  }
```

So when I toggle button number TWO button with number ONE should be toggled instead.

You can see that:

```
ng-reflect-checked="false"
```

but styling isn't updated and it's still toggled.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to achieve what I would like to?

Comment: Hi, Just to clarify, you want button ONE to be toggled/highlighted when you click on button TWO?

Comment: Right. And only button ONE. It leads to more complex problems like selecting one option when 3 others are selected. But to simplify example it is enough that when i press button TWO only button ONE will be toggled

Comment: Will you have a THREE button or will you only have ONE and TWO?

Comment: The main problem was when I had 3 buttons ALL, ONE, TWO. I used a similar approach as in the demo. When ONE and TWO were selected, ALL should be toggled and ONE and TWO should be toggled off. But then the last selected value was toggled ( visually)  as well.

Comment: Have you tried to list the buttons individually in your template rather than for looping over them? might be more code but you have more control over the buttons individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so solution was to replace:

```
   <mat-button-toggle-group
      [multiple]="true"
      (change)="onToggleGroupChange($event)"
    >
```

with

```
   <mat-button-toggle-group
      [multiple]="true"
      (change)="onToggleGroupChange($event)"
      [value]="this.selectedItems"
    >
```

mat-button-toggle-group was an uncontrolled component until value input was provided. Two way data binding wasn't based on values of mat-toggle-buttons but it has its own model.

SOLUTION: [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m32p74?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbutton-toggle-overview-example.ts)